# Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" not found; in SQL statement using the Spring Tool Suite 4 IDE

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jdbc, h2, spring-jdbc

This is the actual error

```
Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/C:/Users/DELL/IdeaProjects/taco-cloud-1/bin/main/schema.sql]: alter table Ingredient_Ref add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" not found; SQL statement:
alter table Ingredient_Ref add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id) [90057-214]
```

This is my sql code. Please is there any syntax error, or is there anything I'm missing?

```
create table if not exists Taco_Order (
    id identity,
    delivery_Name varchar(50) not null,
    delivery_Street varchar(50) not null,
    delivery_City varchar(50) not null,
    delivery_State varchar(2) not null,
    delivery_Zip varchar(10) not null,
    cc_number varchar(16) not null,
    cc_expiration varchar(5) not null,
    cc_cvv varchar(3) not null,
    placed_at timestamp not null
);

create table if not exists Taco (
    id identity,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    taco_order bigint not null,
    taco_order_key bigint not null,
    created_at timestamp not null
);

create table if not exists Ingredient_Ref (
    ingredient varchar(4) not null,
    taco bigint not null,
    taco_key bigint not null
);

create table if not exists Ingredient (
    id varchar(4) not null,
    name varchar(25) not null,
    type varchar(10) not null
);

alter table Taco
    add foreign key (taco_order) references Taco_Order(id);
alter table Ingredient_Ref
    add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id);
```

It's meant to run alongside other codes (html, java) as a web application that fetches these data from this h2 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add primary key (or unique) constraints to your tables before creation of referential constraints.

You also should not use `identity` as data type in modern versions of H2, this syntax is not supported and works only in few compatibility modes for a limited compatibility with historic versions of H2.

You need to replace `id identity` with `id bigint generated by default as identity primary key` in definitions of `Taco_Order` and `Taco` tables and
you also need to replace `id varchar(4) not null` with `id varchar(4) primary key` in definitions of `Ingredient_Ref` and `Ingredient` tables.